Object rendered without material
I have an object in blender that I put a metallic material on and I see it in the viewport but when I render it turns black and the material disappears
i need to render it with transparent background so i don't want to put any background
also tried with lightning and didn't worked
I would appreciate some help, thanks! 

Blender's viewport has 4 shading modes. 


Wireframe
Solid
Material Preview
Rendered

In your screenshot, the viewport is set to Material Preview mode. This means that the EEVEE rendering engine is being used to give you an idea of how your materials look.
The catch here is that Blender automatically uses an environment light (aka. spherical HDR panorama or HDRI) which can be selected in the viewport shading options. 

This environment light will only be used in the viewport for preview purposes.
In the final render, Blender will use the World settings (see below) for the environment light. By default, this is a gray background, and without any other lights in your scene, a reflective material will just reflect that default gray color all over. 

To get nice looking environment lighting in the final render, you must set up an image texture such as an HDRI in the World settings.
To do this, simply click on the yellow dot next to the "Color" input and select "Environment Texture." 
 
Then, you will be able to click the "Open" button and browse to any HDRI on your computer.
If you don't have any HDRIs yet, you can find many high quality ones (including the ones built into Blender for the Material Preview mode) for free on polyhaven.

What you show is the Material preview, this mode uses a default HDRI image that is reflected by your object, but it won't be rendered. If you want your object to reflect something in the rendered image, you need to give an HDRI image to your World, the transparency will still work.
